# Projections of a three-dimensional surface

Tags: plotting, graphics, projection

Here comes some sample data

```
data = {{7.97028, 10., -3080}, {9.19676, 9.6, -3010}, 
        {8.50347, 10.1, -3162}, {9.92937, 9.6, -3090}, 
        {9.14074, 9.8, -3056}, {10.4484, 9.9, -3200}, 
        {8.06007, 10.1, -3130}, {9.82587, 9.8, -3090}, 
        {7.77652, 10.1, -3080}, {10.3784, 10.1, -3190}, 
        {8.77662, 10., -3119}, {8.96429, 10., -3115}, 
        {9.35687, 10., -3108}, {9.61884, 10., -3110}, 
        {9.95886, 9.7, -3100}, {8.12258, 9.7, -3000}, 
        {9.68049, 10.1, -3133}, {10.0694, 9.7, -3120}, 
        {7.7865, 10., -3050}, {8.97676, 9.8, -3055}, 
        {8.11848, 9.8, -3030}, {9.50436, 9.6, -3030}, 
        {8.66752, 9.9, -3085}, {10.1224, 9.6, -3130},
        {9.75226, 9.6, -3060}, {10.3547, 9.9, -3180}, 
        {10.1595, 9.8, -3140}, {10.2115, 9.8, -3150}, 
        {8.75025, 9.9, -3085}, {9.8972, 9.7, -3090}, 
        {10.0716, 10., -3140}, {8.60449, 10.1, -3162}, 
        {8.41269, 10.1, -3160}, {10.3654, 9.6, -3190},
        {7.93197, 10.1, -3110}, {10.4385, 9.8, -3200}, 
        {7.72951, 9.9, -3010}, {9.9803, 9.8, -3110}, 
        {7.52143, 10.1, -3020}, {7.9252, 9.8, -3010}, 
        {9.82945, 9.7, -3080}, {8.45747, 10., -3119}, 
        {9.97527, 10., -3130}, {9.8482, 10., -3120}, 
        {8.04631, 10., -3090}, {10.3021, 9.7, -3170}, 
        {10.1555, 10.1, -3160}, {9.60075, 9.6, -3040}, 
        {8.66849, 10.1, -3161}, {9.39444, 9.7, -3040}};
```

which define the following surface

```
L0 = ListPlot3D[data, InterpolationOrder -> 3, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

My question: I want to create three two-dimensional plots showing the projections of the above surface onto the three primary planes (x,y), (x,z), and (y,z).

I still use version 9.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "projection"? your data is not one-to-one so for a given (y,z) pair there are multiple x value with (x,y,z) on the surface. If it weren't the case you could have simply delete coordinates (e.g. to make an x-y projection you just plot `data[[All,1;;2]]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adapting the solution from [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/Graphics/Graphics3D.html#712335564):

```
Show[ListPlot3D[data, InterpolationOrder -> 3, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"] /. 
     Graphics3D[gr_, opts___] :> 
     Graphics3D[{gr, Scale[gr, #, With[{p = Min[#], q = Max[#]}, p - (q - p)/10] & /@ 
                           Transpose[data]] & /@ (1 + 1*^-3 - IdentityMatrix[3])}, opts],
     PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: shadows]

---

If only the 2D projections are desired, then things are slightly less difficult:

```
lp = ListPlot3D[data, InterpolationOrder -> 3, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];
Table[First @ Cases[lp, GraphicsComplex[pts_, prims_, rest___] :> 
                        Graphics[GraphicsComplex[Drop[pts, None, {3 - k + 1}],
                                                 prims, rest], 
                                 AspectRatio -> {1, 0.4, 0.4}[[k]], Frame -> True], ∞],
      {k, 3}] // GraphicsRow
```

[image: projections]

Comment: I would like the projections to be each one to a two-dimensional plot, not in the the same box with the original surface.

Comment: In v9 I get the following error message "An unrecognized option name ("VertexNormals") was encountered while reading a GraphicsComplex."

Comment: ...should've mentioned you were still on version 9 in your question.